# How do you pass a JSON object to Enyo through a web service?

Tags: json, enyo

I’m trying to pass a JSON object to Enyo using a web server.
The file being loaded from the service in Enyo:

```
{ "Comments" : ["NewComment 1", "NewComment 2", "NewComment 3"  ]}
```

The following callback for the service generates an error saying

```
gotComments: function(inSender, inResponse) {
    this.serverReply = InResponse; // error  uncaught reference error: inResponse not defined
     this.$.list.render();
},
```

When I click on inReply on my chrome debugger it says

```
Object:
Comments: Array[3]
```

How can it say it is not define, if the watch window shows it as

```
Object:
Comments: Array[3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question mixes `InResponse` (capital `I`) and `inResponse` (lowercase `i`). Assuming this is what your *real* code looks like, change

```
this.serverReply = InResponse;
```

to

```
this.serverReply = inResponse;
```

Comment: Next time, run your code through [JSLint](http://jslint.com). It'll catch this sort of error, no need to ask SO.